# Execute server call if first fails in java

Tags: java, exception

I have two ids (id1, id2) and I want to fetch data from server if first fails.

```
try
{
 loadData1(id1);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 loadData2(id2);
}
```

Is this a good practice or is there any alternative for this?

Comment: move it to another try and not into the catch. catch is to handle the exceptions proper

Comment: Put the try catch in a method and if it fails call it again. Make sure you put a counter in it otherwise you might get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Why would there be an exception if loading the first id fails? Why doesn't the return value of the method just indicate the load wasn't successful, e.g. because the id doesn't exist? In general exceptions are meant to be just that, i.e. expected or unexpected conditions that should happen rarely. If you expect an operation to fail for some reason it's often better to make allowances for that, e.g. by checking the preconditions before making the call or proper return values/state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good practice. Try to use the catch block for handling the error/exception and logging the error information. You can have a condition check to see if the `loadData1(id1);` operation is a success so that in the next try-catch block you can add the logic `loadData2(id2);`

```
 boolean loadSuccess=false;
  try
  {
   loadSuccess=loadData1(id1);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     //error handling or logging code goes here
  }
  if(!loadSuccess)
  {
    try
    {
     loadData2(id2);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     //error handling or logging code goes here
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

loadData1 fails when it throws an exception. But loadData2 is there to handle it as long as -

1. loadData2 function call in catch is again wrapped in an effective try-catch.
2. loadData2 is function that already has exception handling implemented.

The rest of the code should continue execution if one of the conditions is met.